# Dropped phone into water and shut down automatically after the logo is displayed

Tags: charging, boot, hardware, shutdown, water-damage

I dropped my phone(Asus Zenfone max pro m1) into water then I took the phone out from the water and turned off and cleaned the phone surface with a dry cloth. Then kept my phone in a pouch with uncooked rice for 4 days. Now I try to turn on it shows the logo and shutdowns automatically. Even I tried to enter into the recovery mode but got failed. But I can enter into the fastboot mode. When I try to charge, the charging indicator fluctuates. Can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that it's malfunctioning because you dropped it in water. Unfortunately hardware issues cannot be fixed remotely. You need to get it fixed by some technician.

Comment: [Relevant iFixIt Q+A](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/374050/Why+is+there+a+spreading+black+spot+on+my+screen#answer374052).

Comment: I gave to technician and now its fixed. No worries

Answer (score 0):

firstly did you completely sink your phone into rice? if at all you did then no wonder your mother board is damaged! like some kind of short circuit might have happened... well you can replace same model mother board or you upgrade to some good affordable motherboard because they cost nearly same price as new phone, you got 2 options buy new phone or buy new motherboard(costs less than new phone).